# How to change a @Binding var from another class?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a View that is included in another View in SwiftUI this way:

1st View

```
struct CircularProgressBar: View {

    @Binding var circleProgress: CGFloat

    var widthAndHeight: CGFloat
    var labelSize: CGFloat?
    var staticColor: Color?
    var progressColor: Color
    var showLabel: Bool?
    var lineWidth: CGFloat?

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .stroke(self.staticColor ?? Color.gray, lineWidth: self.lineWidth ?? 15)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0.0, to: self.circleProgress)
                    .stroke(self.progressColor, lineWidth: self.lineWidth ?? 15)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.width)
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
                if self.showLabel ?? true {
                    Text("\(Int(self.circleProgress*100))%")
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .font(.custom("HelveticaNeue", size: self.labelSize ?? 20.0))
                }
            }
        }
            .frame(width: widthAndHeight, height: widthAndHeight)
    }

}
```

2nd View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var simulator:Simulator
    @State var progress: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(simulator.getName())
                Text("Version: "+simulator.getVersion())
                Spacer()
                Image("logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 40)
            }.padding()

            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("State")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

                CircularProgressBar(circleProgress: $progress, widthAndHeight: 180, labelSize: 30, progressColor: .blue)


                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation{self.updateCircleProg()}
                    //Action here
                }) {
                    Text("Show Logs")
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
    func updateCircleProg(){
        self.progress = CGFloat(Float.random(in: 0 ..< 1))
    }
}
```

I was able to update the UI from another class on the simulator Object since it's declared as `ObservableObject` and has its properties as `@Published`

And I was able to change the `progress` inside the 2nd View.

My Question is: is it possible to change the `progress` of the 1st View which is included in the 2nd View from another class and update the UI? (Out of 2nd View)?

I tried changing it but the UI wasn't updated
here's what I did:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    var simulator : Simulator!
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        simulator = Simulator(name: "simulator", version: "1")
        let contentView = ContentView(simulator: simulator, progress: 0.0)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) { 
            self.simulator.setName(name: "Big Simulator")
            self.simulator.setVersion(version: "2")
            contentView.progress = 0.3
        }
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .miniaturizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, SwiftUI works in different way... so you need

```
class Simulator: ObservableObject {
   @Published var progress: CGFloat = .zero // << and here
```

so update

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) { 
    self.simulator.setName(name: "Big Simulator")
    self.simulator.setVersion(version: "2")
    self.simulator.progress = 0.3    // << modifier here or anywhere
}
```

and

```
VStack(alignment: .center) {
    Text("State")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

    // observe here
    CircularProgressBar(circleProgress: self.$simulator.progress, widthAndHeight: 180, labelSize: 30, progressColor: .blue)
```

**Note:** `@State` is designed to be used **only** inside view, so follow this rule easily take a habit to give state property a **private**, always.

Comment: I updated my question so you can understand what I am trying to do. I want to change the progress value from outside the content view, I tried doing so in the AppDelegate Class as an example

Comment: what if I didn't have the simulator object declared? do I need to declare another object and make it observed like the Simulator object? to sum up, is there another way to have something like @State outside the views? other than Observed object

Comment: @mahdi, SwiftUI view is refreshed reactively, so you need some dynamic model which refresh a view. For now generic purpose entities for this are State and ObservableObject. First for internally initiated refresh, second does the same from outside - so all covered. What's wrong with this?

Comment: nothing wrong with your answer. The way swiftUI is designed bugged me a little. Doesn't conform too much with OOP. Thanks for your help

Comment: for just a single variable "progress" I have to create a whole class and store progress in it. that's where I see they made it complicated